# Regex - match everything without whitespace

Tags: regex, performance

I now using in `Regex` this expressions,

`([\x20-\x7E]+)` - match everything with space

`([\x21-\x7E]+)` - match everything without space

But i need more performance and in benchmark i see that `(.*)` is **2x** more faster than  `([\x20-\x7E]+)`. Then i replaced that.

But how to write `([\x21-\x7E]+)` in `(.*)` ? Or in other words how to modify `(.*)` to match everything without whitespace characters?

Thanks!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

To match everything except whitespace use:

```
[^\s]+
```

or

```
\S+
```

Comment: Or just `\S+`.  But this is much too easy.  This can't be the real answer can it?  Svisstack was asking about benchmarking, so I assume this isn't Svisstack's first time using a Regex?

Comment: @Buh Buh: works little bit slower, i was thinking about performance improvment but this is only 5% slower and i have cleaner code, i forgive this up, this is why i accepted

Comment: Why not `[^\s.]+`?

Comment: But why exclude dot?

Answer (score 0):

I was forced to make the following

```
"^((?!\s).)*$"
```

Or if you want it for multiple symbols

```
"^((?![\s]).)*$"
```

It will be work in Notepad++ too