# JavaScript regex to capture two or three words in separate groups

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match (along with capture groups) the following input:

```
favorite colors are red orange yellow
favorite colors are red orange
```

The first phrase has 3 colors, the second phrase has 2 colors.

My regex is:

```
/favorite colors are (.*) (.*) (.*)/i
```

However, this regex only works if I have 3 colors.  How could I rewrite this regex so that it can also accept 2 colors?  I've tried adding a ? to the end of the 3 capture group but that requires that my input phrase to have a trailing space.

I don't mind having the 3 color be empty in the capture group if the 3rd color isn't supplied.

As per the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451731 post, the suggested fix as `/favorite colors are (.*) (.*)(?: (.*))?/i`, however, it does not work because it matches red orange as group 1, and yellow as group 2, while red should be in group 1, orange should be in group 2 and yellow should be in group 3. The http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991178 post suggests using `[^\s]`, but it turns out that matches trailing dots.

Comment: You might want to ensure that the captured groups only accept single words, rather than `(.*)`

Comment: Hi, please take a look at duplicate topic and if it didn't give you some insights, edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @revo It is not a dupe of [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451731/how-do-i-make-part-of-a-regex-match-optional), since it is not *just* about making a part of a regex optional. See [`favorite colors are (.*) (.*)(?: (.*))?`](https://regex101.com/r/eGTfHV/1), it does not work.

Comment: I added another dupe for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `favorite colors are (.*) (.*) (.*)` pattern requires at least one space between Group 1 and Group 2, and between Group 2 and Group 3.

Besides, to match just word chars, you need to use `\w` instead of the `.` that matches any char but a line break char.

You may use an optional non-capturing group with `\w+` or `\w+` patterns replacing `.*` ones:

```
/favorite colors are (\w+) (\w+)(?: (\w+))?/i
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KxiKVR/3).

Here, `(?: (\w+))?` matches an optional *sequence* of patterns, a space and 1+ word chars (letters, digits or `_`) captured into Group 3.